# saving multiple entities with one to many relationship in breeze and EF code first

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, breeze

saving multiple entities with one to many relationship in breeze and EF code first results two extra empty value entities,

what am i'm doing wrong?

here's my code (i removed all irrelevant entities and scripts from the post)

**Entities**

```
public class Server
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ServerAddress> Addresses { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int DomainId { get; set; }

    public Domain Domain { get; set; }
}

public class ServerAddress
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Ip { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ServerAddressFarm> ServerAddressFarms { get; set; }

    public int ServerId { get; set; }

    public Server Server { get; set; }
}
```

**DbContext**

```
public class PortalDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Server> Servers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ServerAddress> ServerAddresses { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // Server PK
        modelBuilder.Entity<Server>()
            .HasKey(t => t.Id)
            .Property(t=>t.Id)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

         // ServerAddress PK
        modelBuilder.Entity<ServerAddress>()
            .HasKey(t => t.Id)
            .Property(t => t.Id)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);


        // Domain 1-->* Server
        modelBuilder.Entity<Server>()
            .HasRequired(t => t.Domain)
            .WithMany(t => t.Servers)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
            //.HasForeignKey(t => t.DomainId);

        // Server  1-->* ServerAddress
        modelBuilder.Entity<ServerAddress>()
            .HasRequired(t => t.Server)
            .WithMany(t => t.Addresses)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);


    }
}
```

**Angular service**

```
(function () {
"use strict";

angular.module('portalApp')
    .service('serversService', [
        '$q', '$http',
        function ($q, $http) {
            var self = this;

            breeze.NamingConvention.camelCase.setAsDefault();
            self.manager = new breeze.EntityManager('breeze/Servers');

            self.addServer = function(server, serverData) {

                var serverEntity = self.manager.createEntity('Server', server);
                self.manager.addEntity(serverEntity);

                if (serverData.ip1) {
                    serverData.ip1 = self.manager.createEntity('ServerAddress', { ip: serverData.ip1, server: serverEntity });
                    self.manager.addEntity(serverData.ip1);
                    server.addresses.push({ ip: serverData.ip1 });

                }

                if (serverData.ip2) {
                    serverData.ip2 = self.manager.createEntity('ServerAddress', { ip: serverData.ip2, server: serverEntity });
                    self.manager.addEntity(serverData.ip2);
                    server.addresses.push({ ip: serverData.ip2 });
                }

                return self.manager.saveChanges();
            };
        }
    ]);
}());
```

**Angular Controller**

```
(function () {
"use strict";
angular.module('portalApp')
    .controller('serverListCtrl', ['$rootScope', '$scope', 'serversService', 'notificationFactory',
        function ($rootScope, $scope, serversService, notificationFactory) {
            var vm = this;

            vm.addServer = function() {
                serversService.addServer(vm.server, vm.serverData)
                    .then(
                        function (data) {
                            vm.server = { name: null, addresses: [] };
                            vm.serverData = { ip1: null, ip2: null };
                            notificationFactory.success("server was added");
                            vm.getServers(vm.domain);
                        })
                    .fail(
                        function (reason) {
                            notificationFactory.errors(reason);
                        });
            };


            vm.init = function () {
                vm.domain = null;
                vm.server = {name: null, addresses: [{},{}]};
                vm.serverData = { ip1: null, ip2: null};
            };

            vm.init();
        }]);
}());
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You're providing the initalValues argument to `EntityManager.createEntity`.  The object has a "server" property which provides breeze with enough information to automatically wire up the newly created ServerAddress entity with it's parent Server entity.  The `self.manager.addEntity` and `server.addresses.push` lines are unnecessary.    To confirm everything is working properly in terms of your breeze setup, set a breakpoint after the `createEntity` line and examine the server.addresses array.  It should contain the new ServerAddress entity.

Answer (score 1):

removing the unnecessary self.manager.addEntity and server.addresses.push lines solved the problem,
thanks  [Jeremy Danyow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/725866/jeremy-danyow)

```
            self.addServer = function(server, serverData) {

                var serverEntity = self.manager.createEntity('Server', server);
                self.manager.addEntity(serverEntity);

                if (serverData.ip1) {
                    serverData.ip1 = self.manager.createEntity('ServerAddress', { ip: serverData.ip1, server: serverEntity });
                    //self.manager.addEntity(serverData.ip1);
                    //server.addresses.push({ ip: serverData.ip1 });

                }

                if (serverData.ip2) {
                    serverData.ip2 = self.manager.createEntity('ServerAddress', { ip: serverData.ip2, server: serverEntity });
                    //self.manager.addEntity(serverData.ip2);
                    //server.addresses.push({ ip: serverData.ip2 });
                }



                return self.manager.saveChanges();
            };
```